# PHP Accessing array values using Object Operator with key

Tags: php, arrays

Say I have an array like the following:

```php
$arr = array(
    'id' => 123,
    'title' => 'Example Title',
);
```

How come I cannot access the values using PHP's object operator (`->`)? In theory, I should be able to do `$arr->title` but that doesn't work and I have to access it as `$arr['title']` instead.

I've been reading plenty of examples of people using the object operator however it's not returning anything but a null value.

Has something changed in recent versions of PHP or am I misunderstanding the examples given?

Comment: https://3v4l.org/N8jE4  (you can check older version output as well by clicking eol versions option in the example link)

Comment: `In theory, I should be able to do $arr->title` Where you read this , that when you create a array you will can access as object ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this code work 100% fine

```
$arr = (object) array(
    'id' => 123,
    'title' => 'Example Title',
);

echo $arr->title;
```

Comment: Ahh, I was unaware I had to cast the array to an object. Thank you.

Comment: Ahhh, I was unaware that some of my arrays must have been objects, and the  object operator worked. "Suddenly" it stopped working and I wondered why. Thanks!